# Convert $516.91 to 51691

Tags: php

I have an input: 516.91. I need to convert it to 51691.

I write a small test code but it doesn't work.

Some examples:

```
56    -> 5600
56.1  -> 5610
56.13 -> 5613
100   -> 10000
```

How to convert 516.91 to 51691 with PHP ?

```
<?php

$varA = 516.91;                                   

$varB = intval(floatval($varA)*1000/10);


$shouldBe = 51691;


if ($varB == $shouldBe) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "NOK - " . $varB . " != " . $shouldBe;
}
```

Comment: There are issues with PHP's floating value points... You have to be well aware about it... But just giving `intval(($varA)*100);` works...

Comment: Do you just want to have the periods removed?

Comment: I need to multiply by 100. Without the floatval I pass 50% of my use case and with floatval I pass 98%.

Comment: Why all the convertion on another data type and just mutiply * 100? all problems solved. o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok .. I found ... bcmul and it work